# SQL structure for multiple queries of the same table (using window function, case, join)

Tags: sql, join, presto, dense-rank

I have a complex production SQL question. It's actually PrestoDB Hadoop, but conforms to common SQL.

I've got to get a bunch of metrics from a table, a little like this (sorry if the tables are mangled):

```
+--------+--------------+------------------+
| device | install_date | customer_account |
+--------+--------------+------------------+
| dev 1  | 1-Jun        |              123 |
| dev 1  | 4-Jun        |              456 |
| dev 1  | 10-Jun       |              789 |
| dev 2  | 20-Jun       |               50 |
| dev 2  | 25-Jun       |               60 |
+--------+--------------+------------------+
```

I need something like this:

```
+--------+------------------+-------------------------+
| device | max_install_date | previous_account_number |
+--------+------------------+-------------------------+
| dev 1  | 10-Jun           |                     456 |
| dev 2  | 25-Jun           |                      50 |
+--------+------------------+-------------------------+
```

I can do two separate queries to get max install date and previous account number, like this:

```
select device, max(install_date) as max_install_date
from (select [a whole bunch of stuff], dense_rank() over(partition by device order by [something_else]) rnk
      from some_table a
      )
```

But how do you combine them into one query to get one line for each device? I have rank, with statements, case statements, and one join. They all work individually but I'm banging my head to understand how to combine them all.

I need to understand how to structure big queries.

ps. any good books you recommend on advanced SQL for data analysis? I see a bunch on Amazon but nothing that tells me how to construct big queries like this. I'm not a DBA. I'm a data guy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *correlated* `subquery` approach :

```
select t.*
from table t
where install_date = (select max(install_date) from table t1 where t1.device = t.device);
```

This assumes `install_date` has resonbale date format.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(install_date) over (partition by device) as max_install_date,
             lag(customer_account) over (partition by device order by install-date) as prev_customer_account
      from t
     ) t
where install_date = max_install_date;
```